# Uninstalled Firefox still here

Tags: firefox, snap, 19.10, delete, purge

I purged firefox(*) and deleted `/etc/firefox` and `/usr/lib/firefox`, the whole `.cache` thing and so on as already mentioned in [Removing Firefox in Ubuntu with all add-ons like it never existed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed)

After all, I still find "Firefox Web Browser" in All Application and even `firefox --version` shows me (even after reboot)

> Mozilla Firefox 72.0.1.

The command `type firefox` says

```
firefox is /snap/bin/firefox
```

What should I do to completely get rid of it?

Comment: /snap/bin/firefox

Comment: As you see, remove the snap package: `sudo snap remove firefox`

Comment: Ah perfect ... Thx Mate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall a snap package manually?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159280/how-to-uninstall-a-snap-package-manually)

Comment: @karel IMHO your link does not fully answer this question as the OP did not originally know that Firefox had been installed using snap and what it means.

Comment: I suppose you could say that, but I found a line in the question which says *The command `type firefox` says `firefox is //bin/firefox`* so from reading that command I thought it would be fair to assume that the author was aware that his Firefox was a snap package, not an apt package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The page [Removing Firefox in Ubuntu with all add-ons like it never existed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed) addresses Firefox installed using APT but in your case, it has been installed as a [snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763078/snap-in-ubuntu-16-04).

This can be checked using the command `type firefox`. If you get an output like `/snap/bin/firefox`, Firefox is installed using snap on your machine.

To uninstall Firefox which has been installed using snap, use the command:

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```