# Should I uninstall the default snap packages before uninstalling snap?

Tags: snap

I want to uninstall snap from 20.04.1, if I can do so without breaking things. In the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280707/how-to-uninstall-snap), @Lorenz and @pat have provided a process for doing so. I have a couple of questions about this process:

On my fresh 20.04.1 install, several snap packages are already installed:

```
Name               Version             Rev   Tracking         Publisher   Notes
core18             20200929            1932  latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3556cb3       60    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-36-gc75f853     1506  latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snap-store         3.36.0-82-g80486d0  481   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd              2.47.1              9721  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
```

What happens to these packages if I uninstall snap? Are core18, gnome..., and gtk-common-themes required for other (non-snap) packages to run?

If they are needed, will they still receive updates after I uninstall snap? If they aren't needed, should/can I uninstall them before uninstalling snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These packages are only required to run other snaps. Non-snap applications never use them. So if you want to completely get rid of snap, you should uninstall them too.

Comment: Are you sure?  Starting with 20.04 a large portion of things are now Snapped for Ubuntu to use, not just for 'other snaps'.  If you are using a Server you can uninstall snaps with limited damage.  If you are on Desktop you're stuck with snaps.

Comment: @ThomasWard I successfully uninstalled all snaps on an Ubuntu Mate 20.04 desktop with no apparent loss of functionality.  I hope it's not true that you cannot remove snap without loss of functionality; if so, I'll have to choose another distro.

Comment: @Thomas Ward - what exactly do you have in mind? The only snap application installed by default in Ubuntu is Snap Store. Except of it, nothing in the desktop environment is using snaps by default. If you don't plan to install any snap applications and use only software available as .deb packages, then you can remove snaps with no loss of functionality.

Comment: Ubuntu MATE 20.04 works perfectly without snaps.