# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS takes a lot of time long to boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, systemd

This is the log from `systemd-analyze`

```
Startup finished in 6.677s (firmware) + 5.010s (loader) + 5.180s (kernel) + 2min 13.817s (userspace) = 2min 30.686s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 12.124s in userspace
```

And this is the log from `systemd-analyze blame`

```
1min 27.700s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                     
     26.782s snapd.service                                                  
     26.376s networkd-dispatcher.service                                    
     22.288s dev-sda2.device                                                
     22.263s systemd-journal-flush.service                                  
     14.767s fwupd.service                                                  
     13.648s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                             
     13.069s udisks2.service                                                
     12.799s accounts-daemon.service                                        
     11.841s grub-common.service                                            
     10.900s NetworkManager.service                                         
     10.522s dev-loop6.device                                               
      9.941s polkit.service                                                 
      9.440s avahi-daemon.service                                           
      9.435s bluetooth.service                                              
      9.070s dev-loop14.device                                              
      8.937s dev-loop23.device                                              
      8.928s dev-loop24.device                                              
      8.920s dev-loop12.device                                              
      8.866s dev-loop21.device                                              
      8.783s dev-loop13.device                                              
      8.720s switcheroo-control.service                                     
      8.707s thermald.service                                               
      8.694s systemd-logind.service                                         
      8.673s dev-loop15.device                                              
      8.555s dev-loop16.device                                              
      8.533s wpa_supplicant.service                                         
      8.261s dev-loop22.device                                              
      8.231s vboxdrv.service                                                
      8.211s dev-loop4.device                                               
      8.069s dev-loop11.device                                              
      8.056s dev-loop19.device                                              
      8.037s dev-loop18.device                                              
      7.983s dev-loop17.device                                              
      7.979s dev-loop10.device                                              
      7.642s dev-loop20.device                                              
      7.257s dev-loop9.device                                               
      7.158s dev-loop7.device                                               
      7.121s dev-loop8.device                                               
      6.918s dev-loop3.device                                               
      6.713s dev-loop0.device                                               
      6.609s dev-loop5.device                                               
      5.350s bolt.service                                                   
      5.018s upower.service                                                 
      4.719s ModemManager.service                                           
      4.288s dev-loop2.device                                               
      4.096s dev-loop1.device                                               
      3.944s apparmor.service                                               
      3.017s gpu-manager.service                                            
      2.798s snapd.seeded.service                                           
      2.586s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                 
      2.544s systemd-udevd.service                                          
      2.510s rsyslog.service                                                
      2.473s ua-messaging.service                                           
      2.360s gdm.service                                                    
      2.292s colord.service                                                 
      2.156s apport.service                                                 
      1.895s secureboot-db.service                                          
      1.802s snapd.apparmor.service                                         
      1.733s systemd-resolved.service                                       
      1.687s tlp.service                                                    
      1.441s e2scrub_reap.service                                           
      1.287s user@1000.service                                              
      1.217s motd-news.service                                              
      1.122s systemd-random-seed.service                                    
      1.020s systemd-sysctl.service                                         
       933ms snap-vlc-2344.mount                                            
       920ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d15\x2dcore20-14.mount
       916ms snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount                                   
       905ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                                   
       901ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount                        
       839ms pppd-dns.service                                               
       835ms snap-snapd-12398.mount                                         
       829ms snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-2814.mount                            
       796ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                             
       780ms systemd-modules-load.service                                   
       757ms snap-gnome\x2dcalendar-158.mount                               
       738ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                   
       728ms snap-core-11316.mount                                          
       722ms snap-snapd-12159.mount                                         
       649ms snap-snap\x2dstore-547.mount                                   
       630ms snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-2800.mount                            
       625ms snap-vlc-2288.mount                                            
       599ms snap-kdenlive-26.mount                                         
       586ms systemd-sysusers.service                                       
       528ms keyboard-setup.service                                         
       512ms systemd-journald.service                                       
       498ms snap-code-67.mount                                             
       484ms modprobe@drm.service                                           
       482ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount                        
       477ms swapfile.swap                                                  
       463ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3006\x2d0FF4.service          
       446ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service            
       441ms snap-gnome\x2dclocks-375.mount                                 
       424ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                      
       418ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-72.mount                         
       406ms plymouth-start.service                                         
       404ms snap-core-11187.mount                                          
       343ms snap-bitwarden-50.mount                                        
       299ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                  
       296ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount                        
       270ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                    
       270ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount                         
       249ms snap-core18-2074.mount                                         
       224ms dev-hugepages.mount                                            
       223ms dev-mqueue.mount                                               
       220ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                         
       218ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                       
       211ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                      
       207ms ufw.service                                                    
       194ms setvtrgb.service                                               
       186ms snap-core20-1026.mount                                         
       184ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                 
       166ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                     
       159ms snap-core18-1988.mount                                         
       159ms openvpn.service                                                
       151ms snap-auto\x2dcpufreq-71.mount                                  
       148ms virtualbox.service                                             
       128ms kerneloops.service                                             
       114ms plymouth-read-write.service                                    
        96ms snap-bitwarden-51.mount                                        
        95ms console-setup.service                                          
        92ms vboxweb-service.service                                        
        69ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-99.mount                           
        69ms boot-efi.mount                                                 
        27ms vboxautostart-service.service                                  
        26ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service                                
        26ms rtkit-daemon.service                                           
        20ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                  
        14ms dev-loop25.device                                              
        12ms alsa-restore.service                                           
        12ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                        
        11ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                  
        10ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                           
         7ms dev-loop26.device                                              
         2ms snapd.socket
```

Even after reinstalling the OS, the problem persists...

**Can anyone please help me with that, how can I improve the boot time in Ubuntu 20.04?**

*My Laptop: HP 250 G7 Notebook PC
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
Graphics:  Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)*

Comment: Read your output. Ask yourself "*Why does XYZ take so long?*" then research that particular piece of your system. There is no single magical answer; you must learn how boot works to *understand* the problem. Also note that each boot might have very different blame output, so look at the trend of, say, five or more.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your RAM, CPU, you might need to change your distro. Xubuntu or Lubuntu are the lightest. Xubuntu requires 500MB RAM, although 2GB is recommended ([read here](https://xubuntu.org/requirements/)). All apps from Ubuntu GNOME will still work on Xubuntu. Disabling Snap can also help, but not much - that's the way I see it from your systemd-analyze result.

Comment: My laptop has 8 gb of ram and is sufficient for ubuntu

Comment: Then, you try disabling some of the processes above. To disable snap, [read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280707/how-to-uninstall-snap). For plymouth-quit-wait.service, [read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119167/slow-boot-issue-due-to-plymouth-quit-wait-service-ubuntu-18-04). If all the above didn't work, you need to change distro like Xubuntu or Mint. On the sidenote, is your laptop Intel Core i3 or i5? From what I [read here](https://www.techadvisor.com/review/hp-250-g7-3701643/), that laptop model should run on Intel Core i5.